# find index number of json element

Tags: javascript, json

Say I am being provided a json object that looks like this:

```
{"someList": [{"id": "21154859" },{"id": "21154865" },{"id": "21154856" },{"id": "21154870" }]}
```

I want to find out what the index number of the current 'someList' item I am on.
I have the someList item id and it is represented by the var aid and equals : 21154856.

I have created a function like so:

```
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
var jsonLength = data.someList.length;
for ( i=1; i <= jsonLength; i++ ){
        chx = data.someList[i].id;
        if(chx === aid){
            var currentidno = Number(i) + 1;
            $('#page').html('').append(currentidno + ' of ' + jsonLength);
            break;
        }
        }
});
```

When I set this up it works fine and gives me a result like this:
3 of 4

But it feels inefficient and I wonder how it would perform if there were thousands of possibilities.  Can someone weigh in on whether or not this ia the best way to achieve what I want to do and either verify or deny the assumption that this is a good way to accomplish the task?

Comment: Your best bet would be to change the JSON to be simply an array of numbers. That would be the most efficient thing to parse: `Array.indexOf` would then be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The loop is just the way to go. However, if you need to do that search often on many elements, it might be efficient to build an index (or just deliver the JSON as an Array of numbers at once, if there are no other properties):

```
var indexArray = data.someList.map(function(o){return o.id;});
var currentidno = indexArray.indexOf(aid) + 1;
```

Or you could with indexing by object properties, instead of an array:

```
someValues = {"21154859":{index:0},"21154865":{index:1},"21154856":{index:2},"21154870":{index:3},... }; 
// no order needed!
var currentidno = someValues[aid].index + 1;
```

Comment: fantastic advice.  For anyone searching for this subject it makes so much sense to push back and get the js in a format that makes sense like this.  Less code for you to write, less work for the webpage to do.  I used the someValues = {"21154859":{index:0},"21154859":{index:1}'

Comment: Bergi I have started down this road of trying to be explicit with index numbers.  But I cannot read the json file because it is not validating.  If you take your json code out and check in the lint tool it fails.  Am I missing something?

Comment: After some fidgeting I figured out the correct syntax and am leaving here for anyone who finds this question in the future. {
    "someList": {
        "21154856": {
            "index": 2
        },
        "21154859": {
            "index": 0
        },
        "21154865": {
            "index": 1
        },
        "21154870": {
            "index": 3
        },
        "20515039" : {
            "index": 4
        }
    }
}  Unfortunately the loop is still needed for the length value.  But  a quick loop to get the total could be replaced by another node that is populated with the total.

Comment: Finally though the idea works one must sacrifice the array to do it this way therefore having to come up with a loop for the length as well as for finding any particular id by index#.  In other words If you have the id it is easy to get the index number, however the index number does not mean anything because it is not a list of items anymore so there is no someList[0]; or someList[3].  Leaving it an array and using .length and being able to target the first element made up for the processing of the loop to find the current id.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
jQuery(someList).index({"id": "21154859" });
```

where someList is JSON Array.